# Inside WKWebView HTTPRequest interception is possible?

Tags: ios, httprequest, wkwebview

I am try implement interceptions http request and send their through private proxy server if link unavailable, but I am find info that (https://www.programmersought.com/article/71961024600/) it's impossible inside WKWebView. How I can implement this feature use another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible only from system layer check this thread - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660636